# Get number of entries in Dropbox

Tags: java, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am making a script in which folders gets uploaded to Dropbox. So to verify if the file is uploaded I need to get number of directories before and after the upload in the Dropbox.

How can I do this with Java.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The total number of files? Or the files directly in a directory?

Comment: number of directories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IMPORTANT**: Note that this code uses the [Dropbox API v1 Java SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/sdks/java), which is [deprecated](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/). You should use the [Dropbox API v2 Java SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/java) instead.

Use [getMetadataWithChildren](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.7.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxClient.html#getMetadataWithChildren(java.lang.String)) it will return a [DbxEntry.WithChildren](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.7.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxEntry.WithChildren.html) object. This object contain a field [children](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.7.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxEntry.WithChildren.html#children) of type [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html?is-external=true) witch as a [size method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size()).

```
dbxClient.getMetadataWithChildren(path).children.size();
```

Note, getMetadataWithChildren can return `null` and children can be `null` too.

Comment: Note that this code uses the [Dropbox API v1 Java SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/sdks/java), which is [deprecated](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/). You should use the [Dropbox API v2 Java SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/java) instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to verify the uploaded file, you should check the response of the upload itself. It will directly indicate whether the upload succeeded or not. If it was successful, it will return the uploaded file metadata. If not, it will raise an error. There's [an example of uploading with the Dropbox API v2 Java SDK here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/master/examples/upload-file/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/upload_file/Main.java#L48).

If you do want to list the contents of a folder though using the Dropbox API v2 Java SDK though, you should use [`listFolder`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/DbxUserFilesRequests.html#listFolder-java.lang.String-) and [`listFolderContinue`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/DbxUserFilesRequests.html#listFolderContinue-java.lang.String-). There's [an example of that here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/master/examples/web-file-browser/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/web_file_browser/DropboxBrowse.java#L71).